# How to play HTTP live stream on IOS device with Flutter APP?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm looking for approaches to play video Live Stream in Flutter.

I tested on [Chewie](https://github.com/brianegan/chewie) and [Video_player](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/video_player) plugins. It works well on Android but doesn`t on IOS devices. And unfortunately, debug console is empty...
[Here is working .m3u8 file](https://streamvideo.luxnet.ua/news24/smil:news24.stream.smil/playlist.m3u8) I tried to play.

Here is a simple reproducer:

```dart
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(VideoApp());

class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideoAppState createState() => _VideoAppState();
}

class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
      'https://streamvideo.luxnet.ua/news24/smil:news24.stream.smil/playlist.m3u8')
        ..addListener(() {
          if (_controller.value.initialized) {
            print(_controller.value.position);
          }
        })
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              _controller.value.initialized
              ? AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
            child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
          )
              : Container()
            ],
          )
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _controller.value.isPlaying
                  ? _controller.pause()
                  : _controller.play();
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

Maybe somebody has experience with playing Video Stream on IOS with Flutter? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, did you get the solution ?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The video_player plugin doesn't currently support the iOS simulators. Your code is likely working correctly on a physical device.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in:

```
if ([self duration] == 0) {
          return;
        }
```

It is in platform level `FLTVideoPlayerPlugin.m` . Line number 325. It seems like duration is zero for live videos. If you remove that part of code it should work.